# Upgrade CometD from 2.4/2.5 to 2.9.1?

Tags: upgrade, cometd

Can I expect that I replace the Java .jar files and client-side .js files of version 2.4 or 2.5 of CometD in an existing software that is running fine, with the same files in 2.9.1 and it all runs the same?

```
1- Are the API of CometD exactly the same on all 2.x versions? 
2- Is there an upgrade guide that I can use?
```

Also, I noticed that on the client side, CometD 2.4/2.5 is not AMD and is a single file, but on 2.9.1 it is AMD-based. Is there a single .js file that contains all client-side CometD code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expect upgrades from 2.4/2.5 to 2.9.x to be either without problems, or requiring very little changes, so yes, it should be typically be a drop-in replacement.

While you're upgrading, I suggest to move to CometD 3. You can find here the [migration guide](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_migration) from CometD 2.x.

CometD 2.9.x is AMD compliant, and the single file you should include in your HTML is typically `org/cometd.js` along with a *binding* for a toolkit (either jquery or dojo).
If you use extensions, you should add also those, see for example http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_primer, or if you don't want to use Maven, [this other section](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_primer_non_maven_way).

Follow also the [tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials), that should get you going.

Full [documentation link](http://docs.cometd.org).